# How to use IF statements on Access queries?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I can't find an IF statement that will allow me to take different paths on querying, based on a form object's value as a condition.

I am using access 2007-2016 file format.

```
    IIF ([Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01EquipOrfao] = -1) then

    SELECT tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento
    FROM tblEquipamentos
    WHERE (((tblEquipamentos.SetorEquipamento)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![fmr01ListSetor]) AND ((tblEquipamentos.AreaEquipamento)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListArea]) AND ((tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento)=*0000)),

    ELSE
    SELECT tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento, tblEquipamentos.PaiEquipamentoID
    FROM tblEquipamentos
    WHERE (((tblEquipamentos.PaiEquipamentoID)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListEquip]))

    ENDIF
```

I need the code to do the following:

```
IF the checkbox "frm01EquipOrfao" is selected,  
SELECT from my Equipments database all equipment from that specific Sector and Area, with ID ending in 0000  
Else,  
SELECT all equipment from my equipments table that has the value of "[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListEquip]" on their "parentEquipment" field.
```

I know my If statement shown is all wrong but I just put it in an understandable way.

Comment: `IIF` is not the same thing as `IF`. Also `ENDIF` is not the same thing as `End If`. See also https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/if_then.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just combine all this into a single `where` clause.  You do need to select the same columns:

```
SELECT tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento, tblEquipamentos.PaiEquipamentoID
FROM tblEquipamentos
WHERE ([Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01EquipOrfao] = -1 AND
       tblEquipamentos.SetorEquipamento = [Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![fmr01ListSetor] AND
       tblEquipamentos.AreaEquipamento = [Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListArea] AND
       tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento = ?
      ) OR
      ([Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01EquipOrfao] <> -1 AND
       tblEquipamentos.PaiEquipamentoID) = [Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListEquip]
      );
```

Comment: Thanks, Gordon.
I think I am starting to understand how criteria are to be used in Access SQL coding.

The code you sent forward compiled but still didn't do quite what I needed.
But with some more researching I found out I should use "like" instead of "=" sign when using a wildcard.
I just replaced: tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento = ?
WIth this: tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento LIKE "*0000"
And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it that way. Try this:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento, tblEquipamentos.PaiEquipamentoID
FROM 
    tblEquipamentos
WHERE 
    IIF(
        [Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01EquipOrfao] = True,
        (((tblEquipamentos.SetorEquipamento)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![fmr01ListSetor]) AND ((tblEquipamentos.AreaEquipamento)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListArea]) AND ((tblEquipamentos.ID_Equipamento)=*0000)),
        (((tblEquipamentos.PaiEquipamentoID)=[Forms]![frm01_AddEquip]![frm01ListEquip]))
```